# Functions whose Limit is the Factorial Function

Tags: calculus, number-theory, limits, factorial

I want to know examples of functions $f(n)$ whose limit is $n!$ Now, when I say "limit", I don't mean $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{n!}=1$$ (I already know functions like that). I'm referring to functions that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)-n!=0$$ I am looking for functions that do not include factorials itself (that bit should be obvious, but I'm just putting it on record). I am also not looking for summation or product equations.

Comment: I doubt there are simple such examples, except for stuff like $n!+\frac{1}{n}$...

Comment: @Wojowu I see...  I don't care much for simplicity, just that they don't include $n!$ itself (obviously)

Comment: I don't like this question; it's too open-ended, and not well-defined enough. Presumably you're not going to like $\Gamma(n + 1)$ either?

Comment: @TheoBendit No, and I probably should edit it.

Comment: @TheoBendit Edited the question.